# How does std::auto_ptr is used with C++/Tree Mapping

Tags: c++, xml

Saw this tutorial:
http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/#2.2

```
std::auto_ptr<hello_t>
hello (const std::string& uri);

std::auto_ptr<hello_t>
hello (std::istream&);
```

Question> I don't understand how the above code can compile.
Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you

For example,

```
std::auto_ptr<std::string> str( std::string("hello world" ) );
```

The code will not compile because the constructor of the `std::auto_ptr` needs a pointer!

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated. Its replacement since 2011 is called `std::unique_ptr`. The function declarations you quote are examples of ungood style.

Answer (score 2):

Those are function declarations, not variable definitions. You'd need to see the body to know exactly what they do, but they are implementable.

But `auto_ptr` is deprecated since C++11 (and was regarded as fairly perilous before that), so you might interpret that as a signal that the tutorial is a bit dated.